# Unable to mount raid on my NAS, trying to rescue the data, how should I proceed?

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

A short backstory: something happened on my Synology NAS, apparently a buggy mailserver program that came with an update stopped the device from seeing the 2x3TB drives I have.  After a lot of searching and a trying a lot of different solutions I eventually got the drives to show up again but they would not mount.  After struggling, I figured that, because it was set up as a mirror, I could format one drive, mount it and perform the recovery on the other.

EDIT: I had it wrong and was trying to mount the wrong disk (not used to messing around with raid), however, I'm still unable to mount the correct disk, `sda`

```
$ file -s /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: data
```

```
$ mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt               
mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /mnt failed: Invalid argument
```

**Further Info**

```
$ cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext4 rw,relatime,barrier=0,journal_checksum,data=ordered 0 0
/proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
/tmp /tmp tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=4,mode=620 0 0
/sys /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
/proc/bus/usb /proc/bus/usb usbfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/vg1000/lv /volume1 ext4 rw,relatime,synoacl,barrier=0,journal_checksum,data=writeback,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group 0 0
/dev/vg1000/lv /opt ext4 rw,relatime,synoacl,barrier=0,journal_checksum,data=writeback,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group 0 0
```

Comment: Let's start with two simple things, first, `ls -l /dev/md3`. Second, `grep /mnt /proc/mounts`. And a third thing, a little less simple, do those mount lines add any kernel messages (`dmesg`)?

Comment: Another simple thing:  do you have the /mnt directory created?

Comment: (And, also, for anyone else who hits a similar problem: `mkfs` is seldom, nay, almost never the right way to recover from a raid failure.)

Comment: Yes, the /mnt directory exists. @derobert: first gives me `brw-rw---- 1 root root 9, 3 Jan 18  2006 /dev/md3`, second is nothing and third, there's no messages in dmesg pertaining to the failed mount.

Comment: @AndyE What is in `/proc/mounts`? Trying to figure out where the busy message came from (makes it sound like its already mounted somewhere...)

Comment: @AndyE Also, it appears your md3 uses 1.2 superblocks. And that your md0 and md1 do not (I'm guessing they use 0.90, but --detail would say for sure). Are you sure you recreated the array with the right options?

Comment: @derobert: no, I don't think I did recreate the array with the right options.  I was following the advice of someone on the Synology forums who replied to someone with a similar issue, can't seem to find it now, though.  I've added the `/proc/mounts` result to the post.  Note that the `/dev/vg*` stuff is how the NAS mounts storage usually.

Comment: I realise it was a bad idea to do things this way, but I was losing a lot of time sending emails back and forth to Synology's tech support who weren't very helpful.  I figured if I formatted one drive I could run data recovery on the other, which I successfully did, but I have around 80k unsorted files which I'm not looking forward to sorting.  If I could get the drive mounted I could just copy the data to the formatted drive manually with the directory tree intact.

Comment: So, it looks like you have LVM running on that as well. So you may actually have a LVM PV on that RAID set. What do you get from `lvs`, `pvs`, and `vgscan`? Oh, and also, what about `file -s /dev/sdb5`?

Comment: @derobert: I'm sorry, it's my fault, I've been trying to mount the wrong disk!  sdb is already mounted, as indicated by lvs.  However, I'm still unable to mount `/dev/sda1` with `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt`.  The error message is "mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /mnt failed: Invalid argument".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6564/discussion-between-derobert-and-andy-e)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an attempt to summarize from the [chat troubleshooting session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6564).

The setup turns out to be physical disk -> mdraid raid1 -> LVM. So there are several layers to work through. The old setup was (due to unfortunate prior recovery efforts) not available.

However, the NAS gui had been used to create another volume on a different disk, and thankfully the GUI created the new volume exactly the same way. So it was possible to discover the setup from the new disk:

- [`mdadm -E new-disk`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/6564/7080374) provided the offset to the start of the data, under the mdraid layer (2048 sectors).
- [`dmsetup table`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7080921#7080921) provided the start block of the logical volume (relative to the start of the physical volume) (1152 sectors)
- There is a magic number (0x53ef) in the third sector of an ext4 volume. Using `dd` and `xxd`, we verified that the [magic number is present](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7081405#7081405) at that offset on the disk we're trying to recover data from.

Armed with the start sector of the ext4 filesystem, you can use a read-only loop device to recover the data:

```
# losetup /dev/loop0 -o $((512*(1152+2048))) -r /dev/sda1
# mount -text4 -o ro /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

And then copy it off.

Comment: Once again, thank you for the amount of time and effort you put into helping me.  You must have the patience of a saint.